# how to get the tip: man git | grep

Tags: macos, git, grep

I am using a MacBook. i want to know the meaning of the option in `git push --set-upstream git@git.coding.net:de/Bee.git master` .

I want to figure out the use of `--set-upstream`. I can google. And I am willing to use `man git push`.

The result list is too long. So I use `grep` to find it.

Here is what i tried and failed.

```
den% man git | grep [--set-upstream]
zsh: no matches found: [--set-upstream]

den% man git | grep --set-upstream 
grep: unrecognized option `--set-upstream'
usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
    [-e pattern] [-f file] [--binary-files=value] [--color=when]
    [--context[=num]] [--directories=action] [--label] [--line-buffered]
    [--null] [pattern] [file ...]
```

Even:

```
den% man git | grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ]
zsh: no matches found: [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ]
den% man git | grep -abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ 
grep: unknown --devices option
```

Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can easily grep man pages, however you can search within them.

Firstly open the man page normally `man git`

Then hit `/` to search, type in your search `--set-upstream` and hit enter. It should return the first result, to keep searching, hit `/` and then enter again, it'll go to the next result, and so on.

For information on how to use man pages, see `man man`